# How to use terminal from Krusader?

Tags: command-line, user-profile, konsole, krusader

When I try to run the "Start Terminal Here" command I get
Error executing

```
konsole --workdir %d!
```

On the net I found that the reason is that I have konsole is not installed, but I don't have root access and I can't install here anything. I tried putting

```
sh
bash
gnome-terminal
```

but the console is not being shown and nothing happens.

What can I do?

I want to start terminal from current location opened in Krusader.

Comment: krusader is a kde app and gnome-terminal a gnome app so please add the OS version you use (kde/gnome?). Might be relevant to commands you issue on command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal (Konsole) starts in **Applications** | **System** . Try to run the terminal outside krusader, this will tell you if it's a larger problem than krusader.

In krusader; [**settings** | **configure krusader** ]

Under **General**;

```
konsole --workdir %d
```

and under **User Actions**

```
konsole --noclose --workdir %d --title %t -e
```

Comment: I did it, but the error remains.

Comment: that doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory %d
```

Comment: Some explanation?

Comment: in Krusader menu -> Settings -> Configure Krusader... -> Tab "General" -> Terminal: **gnome-terminal --working-directory %d**

Comment: or in Mint Mate: mate-terminal %d

Comment: Press F2 or Left-Bottom Button to call Terminal

Answer (score 8):

To use Konsole (KDE terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```

To use Gnome terminal - alter Krusader settings: 
Under **General**

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory %d
```

Under **User Actions**

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory %d --name %t -e
```

To emulate Konsole **--noclose** parameter in Gnome terminal - open a new gnome-terminal, navigate to **Edit -> Profile settings**. Click on the **"Title and Command"** tab. Change "exit the terminal" to "hold the terminal open".

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Settings panel, there, in "Default Application" you can set you preferred console app.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to install the **konsole** package. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For xfce

```
xfce4-terminal --working-directory %d
```

If you would like open in a new tab, then

```
xfce4-terminal --tab --working-directory %d
```

Comment: what is that thing in the 1st line?

Comment: Please use English in AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

**General**

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory %d
```

**User Actions**

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory %d --name %t -e
```

Mate: since mater-terminal is a fork of gnome-terminal so we need to pass the same arguments

**General**

```
mate-terminal --working-directory %d
```

**User Actions**

```
mate-terminal --working-directory %d --name %t -e
```

IMHO installing just konsole is not correct (but a workaround) if we already have a built-in terminal

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will show you a console login. Use your user account and password to login and issue the install command from there.

(With <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> you will go back to your desktop).

Comment: Wow, this is a window to your beginnings. No code, grammatical mistakes...   by editing I feel like erasing history... sort of (will delete comment)

Comment: The OP wants to open a terminal fromt the current krusader window. With your method you have to login again and you  are not in the krusader dir.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, I've looked into your forum's discussion, I had the same problem, I've installed konsole package by doing `sudo apt-get install konsole` and konsole terminal appeared exactly inside the directory where I clicked to bring up konsole.

Answer (score -1):

You can install **KDE Konsole**. Find it in Software Center and install it.

After that, you can go to the folder where the application you need to launch is found and press the <kbd>F9</kbd> key to open the terminal and run the desired program.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your answer is already posted in https://askubuntu.com/a/388443/790920